# jQuery mouseenter second time then do this

Tags: jquery

Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/sZKeM/1/

So basicly it shows box when I hover button and when I hover out from box it will hide. I want to hide box when I hover again the button and if I hover again it will show box again.

```
$('.btn').mouseenter(function(){
   $('.box').css('display','block');
});

$('.box').mouseenter(function(){
   $('.box').css('display','block');
});

$('.box').mouseleave(function(){
   $('.box').css('display','none');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to understand exactly what you want from your question and comments. Is this the behaviour you're looking for:

http://jsfiddle.net/nSfrK/

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

```
jQuery(".btn").on('mouseover', function (e) {
    jQuery('.btn').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.btn').mouseenter(function(){
   var visible = $('.box').css('display') == "block"
       $('.box').css('display',visible ? '' : 'block');

});
```

Comment: close! but when I mouseout from box, box still shows, thanks!

Comment: well, you should realize that if your document contains multiple divs class'ed with 'box', this will probably not work well for you.. Make sure that each button you have, will 'know' which box to reference, prefereably giving it an id instead of matching its class. the alteration to (".bnt").mouseenter should not interfere with (".box").mouseleave.. but, i probably just dont understand what your goal is :)